# How to display local languages fonts from unicode?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

Basically i am creating an app which have multiple languages fonts means english as well as local language(Hindi & some other) fonts. but the problem is it display only english text not the other.Text in other languages shown in rectangle box. I want to show all types of text. please suggest me.

Here is the snapshot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. here is the [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=798380%5D)
This file support all Indian language fonts and english too. Just copy paste this file in assets filder and include in the code

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/file_name.ttf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```